# JQuery Replace Element w/ Slide Left Effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Currently im using fadeOut animation effect in replace content of a `div` element.

```
$('#divID').fadeOut('slow', function(){
    $(this).replaceWith( $div );
});
```

How can I achieve `slide to left` effect when replace content of the `div` element?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Don't know if there is a specific effect for that, I used `$().animate({left: val})` to achieve that.

```
var width = $(window).width();

$('#divID').animate({left : -width}, 500, function(){ $div.hide() });
$div.css({left: width}).show().animate({left: 0}, 500);
```

You will need to set your elements' css to `position: absolute`, and tune the containers and other items.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e3m7K/2/)