# Sliding elements into a container

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm trying to slide some generated elements periodically into a container. I'm trying to use .animate() of jQuery.

What I have until now:

```
<div id="mainContainer">
     </div>

<div id="photoContainer" class="photocontclass" style="display:none">
        <img id="image" src="@Url.Action("Photo_Read", new { Id = 1})" />
    </div>

<script>
    var photoId = 2;

    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () { getPhoto() }, 3000);
    });

    function getPhoto() {
        $("#photoContainer #image").attr("src", '@Url.Action("Photo_Read")' + '/' + photoId);
        var $new = $('#photoContainer').clone().attr("id", "photoContainer" + photoId);
        $('#timelineContainer').prepend($new);
        $new.show('slow');
        // do animation with animate...
        $new.animate({
            left:'-50%' // which properties should I have?
        }, 2000, "swing", function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        photoId++;
    } </script>

<style>

.photocontclass {
    display:inline;
    margin:10px;
    background-color:white;
    padding:5px;
    position:absolute;
}

#timelineContainer {
    background-color:grey;
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}

</style>
```

The `$("#photoContainer")`should come in from the right side of the container, and come out at the left side... After it should be removed...

I have some doubts:

- Which CSS properties should I have in the `mainContainer` and in the `photoContainer` (position, left, etc...)?
- Should I place the `photoContainer` inside or outside of the `mainContainer`?
- which properties should I have in the animate method?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/15063125/86072. Does this other question answer yours ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find some answers at [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/actree/WUHJE/19/). There is a simple example of what you want to do.

```
<div id="mainContainer">
<div id="photoContainer" class="photocontclass">
    <img id="image" src="@Url.Action("Photo_Read", new { Id = 1})" />
</div>
</div>
```

Click in the red bordered div. In CSS it is important to declare a div with position:relative to wrap arround the div you want to move. The position:absolute and overflow:hidden of the moving div is mantadory. You can hide or remove the div after moving.
I don't know exactly fore what the timeline container is ment for?